# How to merge load event and change event in javascript under one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My `html` code for one bundle of `checkboxes`. i have some bundle of `checkboxes` like this with different class names. I have shown one bundle here.

```
<ul>
    <li><input class="TestAll" type="checkbox" id="select_all"/> Selecct All</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 1</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 2</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 3</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 4</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 5</li>
    <li><input class="Test" type="checkbox"> This is Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

My `javascript` is shown below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function Selection(id, name) {
            var ALL = document.getElementById(id);
            var Single = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

            ALL.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
                for (i = 0; i < Single.length; i++) {
                    Single[i].checked = ALL.checked;
                }
            });

         for (var i = 0; i < Single.length; i++) {
               Single[i].addEventListener('change', function (e) {
                if (this.checked == false) {
                        ALL.checked = false;
                  }
                if ($('.' + name + ':checkbox:checked').length == Single.length) {
                     ALL.checked = true;
                  }
            });
         }
      }
  //    window.onload = Selection;
 </script>
```

here i'm taking the id of the select All `checkbox` and `classname` for other `checkboxes`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Selection('select_all', 'Test');
</script>
```

This function is for the create page. the following function is for edit page.

```
 function SelectionOnLoad(id, name) {
    var all = document.getElementById(id);
    var single = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

    if ($('.' + name + ':checkbox:checked').length == single.length) {
        all.checked = true;
        }
    else {
      all.checked = false;
         }
  }

 $(document).ready(function () {
      SelectionOnLoad('select_all', 'Test');         
   });
```

Is there any ways to do these separated functions under one function ... Any suggestions ?

Comment: Maybe you can take a look about data-binding framework, like knockout.js.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you mean correctly, you may want to use this function:

```
function selectionOnload(id, name) {
    var all = document.getElementById(id);
    var single = document.getElementsByClassName(name);

    if ($('.' + name + ':checkbox:checked').length == single.length) {
        all.checked = true;
    }

    all.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
        for (i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
            single[i].checked = all.checked;
        }
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < single.length; i++) {
        single[i].addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            if ($('.' + name + ':checkbox:checked').length == single.length) {
                all.checked = true;
            } else {
                all.checked = false;
            }
        });
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    selectionOnload('select_all', 'Test');
});
```

Tip: We just need to check all of the checkboxes are checked or not 1 time. If they are, set `checked` attribute to `all`. Otherwise, it will be `false`.

And we can also write the events inside the *selectionOnload* function/